# Campy novel: Inca Kola sales/promotion and a cat that rules the world/universe

Tags: story-identification, novel

Looking for the title of a campy novel about Inca Kola sales/promotion and a cat that rules the world/universe.

Read it about 20 years ago thought I had saved but can't find. Gave many books to my daughter who got rid of some. Really funny, would like to read again.

Comment: I sure hope someone answers this, I'd love to read this one.

Comment: *a cat that rules the world/universe* did you check non-fiction? (I asked my cats).

Answer (score 5):

I believe the book you’re thinking about is *Cat.A.Lyst* (1991) by Alan Dean Foster.

The story features actor Jason Carter & wardrobe mistress Marjorie Ashwood.  Jason finds a disc which they return to its owner Bruton Fewick.  Next the 2 of them head to Lima, Peru, followed by a flight to Cuzco, Peru where they find a stray cat named Macha.

From there they go to some ancient Incan ruins and are waylaid by local thugs headed by Fewick who has his own cat, Moe, with him.  In turn this group is captured by another group headed by Francesa da Rimini, who has the Fernandez brothers with her.

This is the part that clued me into the book you’re thinking of because the Fernandez brothers are bottlers of Inca Cola!  Throughout the story there is also an alien entity overlooking the whole thing with the main plot of the story concerning some advanced interplanetary Incas intent on revenge against the Spanish.

The cats come in as activators of an interdimensional portal and the aliens apparently have a feline quality to them as well.  I hope this is the book you’re thinking of.

[image: book cover with cat sitting on a globe]